# Ubuntu 13.10 Eclipse 3.8.1 unresolved inclusion <string.h>

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I've just installed **Ubuntu 13.10** and **Eclipse 3.8.1** with c++ development tools.

However, my C++ files get tons of "Unresolved Inclusion" error on anything outside of the project directory.  I've seen that lots of other people have similar problems but my version of eclipse seems different.  For example, if I open `Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols`, the options look completely different than other instructions imply.

Comment: Can you confirm if gcc/g++ is installed in your system?
`which gcc` or `which g++` also `gcc --version`

Comment: yes, both are installed

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1

Comment: Have you tried to create simple Hello World project from Eclipse IDE and tried compiling that. The inclusion errors normally occur when Eclipse doesn't find the include path for the headers. Default installation of `c++` headers is `/usr/include/c++/xxx/` (you need to confirm this on your system. The defaults paths are available system wide in linux. if you can compile your program on console then it should also be picked up by eclipse. if not you should try including the header path manually.

Comment: HelloWorld project compiles and runs fine.  My project compile fine from console, but eclipse still shows all the "Unresolved Dependency" errors.  How do I include the header path manually?

Comment: Why don't you create a "Hello World" project, delete the default `cpp` file from it (the one that contains the main function) copy all your `.cpp` and `.h` files into the project directory and compile and run your project from Eclipse.

Comment: OK that worked. Thanks! I'll have to figure out how to generate those includes manually in the future.